# STL batch exporter alters file name

Tags: export, stl

Blender has a built in option to batch export STL files but it replaces spaces, "(", "[" with underscores which I don't want.

For example:

What the object is named: `Sprgr L4.5 Patr (DoppZ S-60 Fl) 1-1 scale - [ 88mm KwK 36 ]`

What it actually exports as: `Sprgr_L4_5_Patr__DoppZ_S-60_Fl__1-1_scale_-___88mm_KwK_36__`

Does anyone have a working plugin for 2.8x that doesn't screw with the name? Or perhaps some simple way to avoid this problem? I don't want to be renaming each file manually. Especially when I have over 10 000 files to export.

I wouldn't mind trying to hack together a plugin but my understanding of python is basically non-existent. And taking an existing obj batch exporter plugin and replacing "obj" with "stl" is obviously not going to work.

This is the obj batch exporter that I'm using and works great:

```
# ##### BEGIN GPL LICENSE BLOCK #####
#
#  This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
#  modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License
#  as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2
#  of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
#
#  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#  GNU General Public License for more details.
#
#  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
#  along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software Foundation,
#  Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA 02110-1301, USA.
#
# ##### END GPL LICENSE BLOCK #####
# <pep8 compliant>

bl_info = {
    "name": "Export multiple OBJ files",
    "author": "p2or, brockmann",
    "version": (0, 2, 0),
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
    "location": "File > Import-Export",
    "description": "Export multiple OBJ files, UV's, materials",
    "warning": "",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "tracker_url": "",
    "category": "Import-Export"}


import bpy
import os

from bpy_extras.io_utils import ExportHelper

from bpy.props import (BoolProperty,
                       FloatProperty,
                       StringProperty,
                       EnumProperty,
                       CollectionProperty
                       )


class ExportMultipleObjs(bpy.types.Operator, ExportHelper):
    """Batch export objects as obj files"""
    bl_idname = "export_scene.batch_obj"
    bl_label = "Batch export OBJ's"
    bl_options = {'PRESET', 'UNDO'}

    # ExportHelper mixin class uses this
    filename_ext = ".obj"

    filter_glob = StringProperty(
            default="*.obj;*.mtl",
            options={'HIDDEN'},
            )

    # List of operator properties, the attributes will be assigned
    # to the class instance from the operator setting before calling.

    # context group
    use_selection_setting: BoolProperty(
            name="Selection Only",
            description="Export selected objects only",
            default=True,
            )
    use_animation_setting: BoolProperty(
            name="Animation",
            description="Write out an OBJ for each frame",
            default=False,
            )

    # object group
    use_mesh_modifiers_setting: BoolProperty(
            name="Apply Modifiers",
            description="Apply modifiers (preview resolution)",
            default=True,
            )

    # extra data group
    use_edges_setting: BoolProperty(
            name="Include Edges",
            description="",
            default=True,
            )
    use_smooth_groups_setting: BoolProperty(
            name="Smooth Groups",
            description="Write sharp edges as smooth groups",
            default=False,
            )
    use_smooth_groups_bitflags_setting: BoolProperty(
            name="Bitflag Smooth Groups",
            description="Same as 'Smooth Groups', but generate smooth groups IDs as bitflags "
                        "(produces at most 32 different smooth groups, usually much less)",
            default=False,
            )
    use_normals_setting: BoolProperty(
            name="Write Normals",
            description="Export one normal per vertex and per face, to represent flat faces and sharp edges",
            default=False,
            )
    use_uvs_setting: BoolProperty(
            name="Include UVs",
            description="Write out the active UV coordinates",
            default=True,
            )
    use_materials_setting: BoolProperty(
            name="Write Materials",
            description="Write out the MTL file",
            default=True,
            )
    use_triangles_setting: BoolProperty(
            name="Triangulate Faces",
            description="Convert all faces to triangles",
            default=False,
            )
    use_nurbs_setting: BoolProperty(
            name="Write Nurbs",
            description="Write nurbs curves as OBJ nurbs rather than "
                        "converting to geometry",
            default=False,
            )
    use_vertex_groups_setting: BoolProperty(
            name="Polygroups",
            description="",
            default=False,
            )

    use_blen_objects_setting: BoolProperty(
            name="Objects as OBJ Objects",
            description="",
            default=True,
            )
    group_by_object_setting: BoolProperty(
            name="Objects as OBJ Groups ",
            description="",
            default=False,
            )
    group_by_material_setting: BoolProperty(
            name="Material Groups",
            description="",
            default=False,
            )
    keep_vertex_order_setting: BoolProperty(
            name="Keep Vertex Order",
            description="",
            default=False,
            )
    axis_forward_setting: EnumProperty(
            name="Forward",
            items=(('X', "X Forward", ""),
                   ('Y', "Y Forward", ""),
                   ('Z', "Z Forward", ""),
                   ('-X', "-X Forward", ""),
                   ('-Y', "-Y Forward", ""),
                   ('-Z', "-Z Forward", ""),
                   ),
            default='-Z',
            )
    axis_up_setting: EnumProperty(
            name="Up",
            items=(('X', "X Up", ""),
                   ('Y', "Y Up", ""),
                   ('Z', "Z Up", ""),
                   ('-X', "-X Up", ""),
                   ('-Y', "-Y Up", ""),
                   ('-Z', "-Z Up", ""),
                   ),
            default='Y',
            )
    global_scale_setting: FloatProperty(
            name="Scale",
            min=0.01, max=1000.0,
            default=1.0,
            )

    def execute(self, context):                

        # get the folder
        folder_path = os.path.dirname(self.filepath)

        # get objects selected in the viewport
        viewport_selection = context.selected_objects

        # get export objects
        obj_export_list = viewport_selection
        if self.use_selection_setting == False:
            obj_export_list = [i for i in context.scene.objects]

        # deselect all objects
        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

        for item in obj_export_list:
            item.select_set(True)
            if item.type == 'MESH':
                file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, "{}.obj".format(item.name))

                bpy.ops.export_scene.obj(
                        filepath=file_path,
                        use_selection=self.use_selection_setting,
                        axis_forward=self.axis_forward_setting, 
                        axis_up=self.axis_up_setting,
                        use_animation=self.use_animation_setting, 
                        use_mesh_modifiers=self.use_mesh_modifiers_setting,
                        use_edges=self.use_edges_setting, 
                        use_smooth_groups=self.use_smooth_groups_setting,
                        use_smooth_groups_bitflags=self.use_smooth_groups_bitflags_setting, 
                        use_normals=self.use_normals_setting,
                        use_uvs=self.use_uvs_setting, 
                        use_materials=self.use_materials_setting,
                        use_triangles=self.use_triangles_setting, 
                        use_nurbs=self.use_nurbs_setting, 
                        use_vertex_groups=self.use_vertex_groups_setting, 
                        use_blen_objects=self.use_blen_objects_setting, 
                        group_by_object=self.group_by_object_setting, 
                        group_by_material=self.group_by_material_setting, 
                        keep_vertex_order=self.keep_vertex_order_setting, 
                        global_scale=self.global_scale_setting
                )
            item.select_set(False)

        # restore viewport selection
        for ob in viewport_selection:
            ob.select_set(True)

        return {'FINISHED'}


# Only needed if you want to add into a dynamic menu
def menu_func_import(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(ExportMultipleObjs.bl_idname, text="Wavefront Batch (.obj)")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ExportMultipleObjs)
    bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_file_export.append(menu_func_import)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ExportMultipleObjs)
    bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_file_export.remove(menu_func_import)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    #bpy.ops.export_scene.multiple_objs('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

Would greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: This is a Blender internal thing. It's afraid of spaces and . , bc. some platforms might interpret them differently. So blender replaces in any filenames in export scripts the spaces by _ . I don't think there is a way around it, other than creating a second script that replaces the special characters by allowed characters in your object names.

Comment: Well the OBJ batch exporter which I included does not do this so it clearly can be made in a way that it does not add underscores and just keeps original name of the object.

Comment: btw, a lazy approach would be to take the obj exporter and replace every _obj and .obj with _stl and .stl, might just work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were right, it's in the .stl batch exporter. I ran into the same problem with .FBX and apparently gave up too soon.
Go to the directory

```
<path to blender.exe>\2.83\scripts\addons\io_mesh_stl
```

and open the

```
__init__.py
```

line 299, replace

```
keywords_temp["filepath"] = prefix + bpy.path.clean_name(ob.name) + ".stl"
```

by

```
keywords_temp["filepath"] = prefix + ob.name + ".stl"
```

You may want to make a safety copy first...
Use the built-in stl exporter, but be sure that you don't use characters that are not allowed in filenames. This is why Blender cleans the names, it's less prone to error.

Comment: Thank you very much! This works great and it's so simple!